# How to resolve "Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' " in .Net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core

when I am running my application then it's showing me error like `Could not load type 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60`.

My csproj file contains code like below :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Insurance_Customer_Portal_API</RootNamespace>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="SwashBuckle.AspNetCore.MicrosoftExtensions" Version="0.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Is there any things which I need to change in code ?

Answer (score 2):

You have some dependencies in your project that are not required anymore, which are causing a mismatch of actually used DLLs that end up in the build-output.

1. When your project uses `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` and >=
   `netcoreapp3.0`, a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` **is not
   required** so that line can be safely removed.
2. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` is also part of the framework now so **you
   don't need** an explicit reference.
3. Last but not least, **add a NuGet reference** to
   `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` which can be found
   [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/).

Comment: So should I add `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="3.1.0" />` in csproj file ?

Comment: No, you have to remove it, as stated before.

Comment: I am using `1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`, `2. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer`, `3. SwashBuckle.AspNetCore.MicrosoftExtensions`, `4. Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI`. But still it's showing me same error. Still am I wrong on any page ?

Comment: I just saw that `SwashBuckle.AspNetCore.MicrosoftExtensions` has very old dependencies and has not been updated since 2018. Can you try removing the dependency?